# Clarification on Modular Equivalence in Generalized Sumcheck in RZ21

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm studying generalized sumcheck in RZ21 P.10 and have come across a modular equivalence that I'm trying to understand. The specific step that's unclear to me is the following equivalence:

$$ 
\left(\sum_{\mathsf{h} \in \mathbb{H}} P(\mathsf{h}) \lambda_\mathsf{h}(X)\right)\left(\sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}} \lambda_s(v)^{-1} \lambda_s(X)\right) - \sigma = 
\left(\sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}} P(s) \lambda_s(v)^{-1}\lambda_s(X)\right) - \sigma \mod t(X)
$$

**Notation**:

1. $\lambda_{\mathsf{h}}(X)$ and $ \lambda_{s}(X)$ are the Lagrange basis polynomials associated with elements.
2. $\mathcal{S}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{H}$.
3. $\sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}} P(s) = \sigma$.

**Context**:
This theorem extends the univariate sumcheck of Aurora to work not only for multiplicative subgroups of finite fields.

Reference:
[RZ21], https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/590.pdf, P.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the whole equation in the paper is a congruence modulo $t(x)$, which is the vanishing polynomial of $\mathbb{H}$.

The congruence holds because, since $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{H}$, we can calculate the product in evaluation basis by multiplying evaluations at each point in $\mathcal{S}$. The evaluations at points in $\mathbb{H} \setminus \mathcal{S}$ vanish because they are zero in the sum over $\mathcal{S}$ on the left-hand-side.

Comment: I've updated with your edit, thank you. However mathcal doesn't work with HTML+CSS, it needs to be rendered with SVG. ref: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35298/why-using-mathcal-command-produce-a-square

Comment: Does this equivalence means we only consider the evaluation at point in H for the rest of paper? This doesn't seems to hold outside of multiplicative group?

Comment: Re: the font issue, as pointed out at the end of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35731/185422 , updating MathJax would fix the problem. So that's crypto.stackexchange's bug.

Comment: $t(x)$ is the vanishing polynomial of $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: I'm also wondering if the equation doesn't hold when $X$ is not in $\mathbb{H}$. If we flatten the equation, take one term for example, we could get a term like $P(\mathsf{h_3}) \times \lambda_{h_3}(X) \times  \lambda_{h_3}(V)^{-1} \times \lambda_{h_3}(X)$. With $X =  \mathsf{h_3}$, this term does not vanish; with other element in $\mathbb{H}$, this term vanishes. However, with element outside of $\mathbb{H}$, this term doesn't vanish either. (not 1 and 0).
I'm not sure if I'm getting anything wrong.

Comment: thank you, I understand why it hold, it only need to hold in the range of vanishing polynomial, since it's modulus